# line-height textarea

Tags: html, textarea

Currently, my textarea is displayed like this:
[click here to see the picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ws2g64ee2pmbgbq/textarea.PNG).

I would like that height between each lines be less important.

**UPDATE:**

I tried line-height in the css file:

```
textarea{ line-height: 120%; }
```

but it doesn't work, just reduces the textarea height and doesn't reduce the height between lines.

How can I do it?

Comment: Where did you try line-height on?

Comment: i tried line-height in css file `textarea{
 line-height: 120%;
}` but it doesn't work

Comment: The dropbox file is gone. Could you re-add it right to your question?

Answer (score 2):

You may try `percentage`, `em`, `px` etc. and choose one for you. Some browsers like firefox have some errors with this.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/WSAdq/)*** is a working live demo.

Comment: when i try on http://jsfiddle.net the textarea is displayed correctly without line-height. but with my files it doesn't work correctly and same using line-height.

Comment: I think problem is my favorite browser(mozilla). I a correct display when i using chrome. Now, how can I fix compactibility for all famous browser (mozilla,IE,Safari) ?

Answer (score 0):

set padding-top to 0px that should reset the line height of the textarea